# Write a Mathematica program to find the four known factorions

Tags: combinatorics, mathematica

so i have come up with code that will find the four factorion numbers. I have a bunch of ideas of how it needs to be done theoretically but its still not quite clicking for me not too mention i am new to mathematica so the syntax is a bit confusing. So can anyone show me the proper code with brief explanations?

Comment: Is this what you mean? http://oeis.org/A014080

Comment: Yeah that's what i mean. Wow what a good website too i bookmarked it i can definitely see this coming in handy thank you : )

Comment: Did you see the Mathematica code that is on that page?

Comment: yeah i saw it. Its more or less what Calle has said below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, the numbers are so small we can do this very quickly by just testing for each combination below a certain threshold:

```
Reap[If[Total@Factorial[IntegerDigits[#]] == #, Sow@#] & /@ Range[50000]][[2]]
```

Which returns

```
{{1, 2, 145, 40585}}
```

Comment: Yeah, that makes complete sense i don't know why i didn't think of that hahaha. Thanks a lot i appreciate i understand everything that's going on  in the code to besides the "Reap" function you are using. I have never seen it before but i will look this function up in mathematica for further incite. I just hope that sooner or later i can start recognizing that there are alternate ways to solve a problem when i look at it. Thanks so much for the help its appreciated. I

Comment: What is the purpose of the 2 at the end ?

Comment: @Achilles Look up Part in the docuentation. Reap reurns a list; the first part is the result of the calculation as it would have been without Reap present. The second part is a list of valued that were "sown".